# SERVER FileUpload Network Shared / Ruta Compartida

Tags: asp.net, mvc, fileupload

ASP.Net MVC - AdoDB

Utilizaba para cargar y descargar desde el servidor web donde publiqué mis archivos de esta forma, funcionaba correctamente.

```
Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/pdfDocuments/");
```

Pero ahora, quiero enviarlos a otra ruta fuera del servidor web, dentro de un directorio de red (carpeta compartida). Necesito tu ayuda porque ya probé esto:

```
Server.MapPath(@"\\sharedfolder\UploadedFiles\pdfDocuments\");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no necesitas el Server.MapPath, puedes usar directamente la ruta UNC para copiar los ficheros en la carpeta compartida.

Comment: string fullPath = Path.Combine(@"\\usr04\DIRPMPDI\Projectos\", Proj); Asi no me esta funcionando.

Comment: ¿La identidad con la que corre el Application Pool tiene acceso a esa carpeta? Si desde el servidor, logueado con tu cuenta, tienes acceso a la carpeta, puedes probar a hacer correr el pool con tu cuenta (para comprobar si ese es el problema). Sino tendrás que darle permisos a IISUSRS o IUSR (ahora mismo no recuerdo la identidad exacta)

Comment: Probare a ver. Gracias.

Comment: Le aplique todos los permisos en el IIS pool. Listo. Worked. Gracias.

Comment: Estupendo ¿podrías votar la respuesta si te ha sido útil?